# Prevent (stop) Apache from logging specific AJAX / XmlHttpRequests?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest, logging

I'm working on a site where the main idea is to do a lot of **xmlHttpRequests** in a loop (or loop like construct). But the thing is that every time I access the file on my server from the **javascript** it is logged in **access log on the server**. Over time the access log file gets so big it slows down the further requests.

Is there a way to tell the apache (I guess) not to log the access to this file if its correct? (I'm sending a get with a password (always different) to this file.)
The access to the file will be from different IPs.
I don't want to stop all the logging, just the "approved" one.

Comment: I've never heard of logging getting slow because the log file is too big.

Comment: try doing over 20 accesses per second lets say 15 minutes with no break... the access log file gets big...

Comment: I'm not denying that the log will get big (although 20 lines per second doesn't sound like too much), just that I don't see how a big log file will slow down a web server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No problem. Just look at the example from [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html) (a place where you might want to look, if you happen to have an apache-related question in the future).
For example:

```
# Mark requests for the AJAX call
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/myajaxscript\.php.*$" dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/myotherajaxscript\.php$" dontlog
# Log what remains
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

Comment: I read the Apache documentation and understand your comment, but what if I just want to prevent logging of a .php script without setting up a new CustomLog? My site is on Hostgator and I don't know or want to change the rest of the access log setup. Is it possible to just add a condition?